# createjs mask a Bitmap with another Bitmap

Tags: html, createjs, easeljs

I'm trying to mask a [Bitmap](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Bitmap.html) object with another `Bitmap`, but so far with actual success.
There's a [jsfiddle by Lanny](http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/T8ukz/2/), but it involves a [Shape](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Shape.html) object being the mask, so my questions are:

1. Can you use an alpha channel from another bitmap to mask a createjs `Bitmap` object?
2. Is it possible to use an alpha channel from a png image as a mask?

Comment: the docs say `mask` can be only a `Shape`

Comment: what about [AlphaMaskFilter](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/AlphaMaskFilter.html)?

Answer (score 1):

@bks's comment is correct. You can use AlphaMaskFilter to use one image to mask another.

From the docs: http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/AlphaMaskFilter.html

```
 var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap("path/to/image.jpg");
 bmp.filters = [
     new createjs.AlphaMaskFilter(box.cacheCanvas)
 ];
 bmp.cache(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Ensure you cache the bitmap after applying the filter. Keep in mind filters can be slow, so don't update it every frame.

Cheers.

Comment: Ok i see. Now what about mp4 with another mp4 as the alpha channel of the video? I know that you can play a mp4 video in createjs by creating a Bitmap object with an html video element as it's parameter. My goal is to make a transparent video without using webm format

Comment: In theory you can do this with AlphaMaskFilter, but honestly you aren't likely to get the performance you want, since constant caching and filters is quite expensive.

Comment: Does it matter how big is the cached object? Mine should be about 200x200, and the source file is around 250KB